# Freemarker assign value to variable

Tags: freemarker

I'm having trouble while trying to assign value to a variable using Freemarker.

```
<#if size??>
<#assign num=size?number>
<#if (num>0)>       
    <#list 0..num-1 as i>
        <#if .vars['abc'+i?c] = "test"> 
            <#assign .vars['abc'+i?c] = .vars['abc'+i?c]?replace("test","Test")>
        </#if>
    </#list>
</#if>
```

This is the error message:  Encountered ".", but was expecting one of:
STRING_LITERAL
RAW_STRING
ID
Can anyone help me with this?
Thank you.

Comment: Off topic, but you don't need `#if` + `#list` for such situations, just use a range with exclusive end, like `<#list 0..!num as i>`. (Requires FreeMarker 2.3.21.)

Answer (score 0):

You can only write top-level variables in a FreeMarker template. Also you can't assign to a variable with dynamically constructed name, except with an `?interpret` hack: `<@"<#assign abc${i?c} = abc${i?c}?reaplce('test', "Test")>"?interpret />`. Obviously that's horrid... BTW, what's the use case here? Why do you need to assign to dynamically constructed variable names?